# How to fix "Error: [MissingControllerException] " in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, exception

After upgrading php version now its showing following error message on my CakePHP based website.

```
 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class Gems.pngController could not be found.
 #0 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/webroot/index.php(111):       
 Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
 #1 {main} - http://www.example.com/gems.png
```

I am using following code in .htaccess (in webroot)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, its showing an warning message on webpage.
"*Strict (2048): Declaration of FileComponent::startup() should be compatible with Component::startup(Controller $controller) [APP/Controller/Component/FileComponent.php, line 0]*"

I am really struggling to find a solution for all issues.

Advance Thanks

Comment: I suppose that `gems.png` exists, doesn't it? Does it load correctly if you rename the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Yes, if I go to http://www.example.com/gems.png then I can see the image.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. And PHP version should not be relevant here since the whole point of the rewrite rule is to avoid calling PHP at all for assets. Weird...

Comment: I am also feeling weird after seeing this error because nothing changed except php version upgrade.

Comment: So where is the image actually located? What does your document root configuration look like? Is `mod_rewrite` working at all? As for the strict warning problem, you can easily find an answer to this here on SO or via google.

Comment: as for the warning, with php 5.4, in cakephp when u have function e.g. beforeSave() or in ur case startup in ur component, u should put the functions' arguments as well. So in your FileComponent component change the startup function to `startup(Controller $controller)`. In case of beforeSave it should be `beforeSave($options = array())`

Answer (score 0):

I was using CakePHP 2.8 and PHP 5.6, upgraded to PHP 7.2 and got the same error!

Used PHP 7.0 instead of PHP 7.2 and everything went back to normal.